# Simultaneous Count and Sort in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to obtain counts of a certain categorical variable in 2 separate columns, with each column reflecting the presence or an absence of an indicator variable. This is for a very large data frame. Here is an example data frame to further illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
X <- (1:10)
Y <-  c('a','b','a','c','b','b','a','a','c','c')
Z <- c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
test_df <- data.frame(X,Y,Z)
```

I would like to make a new DF grouped by 'a','b', and 'c' with 2 columns to the right, one with counts of the letter for Z==1 and the a count of that letter for  Z==0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
res <- test_df %>% group_by(Y,Z) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Z,values_from=N,
              values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Y [3]
  Y       `0`   `1`
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 a         2     2
2 b         1     2
3 c         0     3
```

Comment: I apologize, I had in mind something a little different, specifically, I had been thinking of a left head column with only 3 rows, one for 'a', 'b', and 'c'. The next-right column would have the sum of 'a' for z=1, and next to that sum of 'a' for z=0, and then likewise for 'b' and 'c'

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet No worries, I have added an update, please let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thank you this is much closer. I apologize to be annoying, I was wondering if it was possible to only have 2 columns to the right of Y, one being Z=1, the other being Z=0, and then the counts populated accordingly...

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet I have added an update, let me know if that works!

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting an error, and then I saw an something with the output from your code:
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Y' (override with `.groups` argument); and then, also, in your output, it says there are 0 a's with z=0, likewise for 'b' and 'c', but there are definitely entries for all letters for which z=0

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet I have added a new update, the messages you get are only warnings from the functions so no issue. Please let me know if that works for you or if any change is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `aggregate` + `reshape`

```
replace(
  u <- reshape(
    aggregate(X ~ ., test_df, length),
    idvar = "Y",
    timevar = "Z",
    direction = "wide"
  ),
  is.na(u),
  0
)
```

giving

```
  Y X.0 X.1
1 a   2   2
2 b   1   2
5 c   0   3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test_df)

test_df[ , z1 := sum(Z==1), by=Y]
test_df[ , z0 := sum(Z==0), by=Y]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `values_fn` in `pivot_wider` to do this in a single step

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test_df %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Z, values_from = X, 
         values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Y       `0`   `1`
#   <chr> <int> <int>
#1 a         2     2
#2 b         1     2
#3 c         0     3
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can use `table` :

```
table(test_df$Y, test_df$Z)
   
#    0 1
#  a 2 2
#  b 1 2
#  c 0 3
```